# $_POST['message'] gives a 404

Tags: 404-error, api, sms

I am using Wordpress 3.3.1 and building a small API to be able to send an SMS to insert data.

```
<?php 
/**
 * Template Name: API: Response
 *
 */

print_r('hello');

?>
```

The following `$_POST` variables are being sent from the SMS provider

```
$_POST['message']
$_POST['from']
```

When using `$_POST['message']`, `$_GET['message']` or `$_REQUEST['message']` Wordpress gives me a 404. Works like a charm when using `$_POST['_message']`.

Any ideas? Can't find it in the reserved taxanomies.

Comment: Try `var_dump( $_REQUEST );` instead of `print_r('hello');`.

Answer (score 0):

To insert a post into the WordPress database, whether you are doing it as a logged in user to the current WordPress installation or over XML-RPC (or any other remote methodology) you need to be using something along the lines of;

```
  $the_post = array(
     'post_title' => 'Post Title',
     'post_content' => 'My post content',
     'post_status' => 'publish',
     'post_author' => 1,
  );


  wp_insert_post( $the_post );
```

In the case of using a form or some other programmatic means to insert a post, your code might look like this;

```
  $the_post = array(
     'post_title' => 'Post Title',
     'post_content' => $_POST['message'],
     'post_status' => 'publish',
     'post_author' => 1,
  );


  wp_insert_post( $the_post );
```

The bottom line is this, no matter how you decide to insert a post - be it via sending an SMS, using a remote form, smoke signal or the like - your code that handles and processes the data to be inserted must reflect the above examples (in its most simplistic form).

**So, what does your code look like that is handling the processing of your incoming SMS message?**

---

References:

`wp_insert_post` - [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post)

Comment: I have no issues creating the page, but when using $_POST['message'] (or any other than that) I receive a 404 from Wordpress.

I've even cleared everything from the template, only using this:


`<?php 
/**
 * Template Name: API: Response
 *
 */

print_r('hello');
?>`

/api/response/?message=lalalala

Gives a 404.

/api/response/?_message=laalalal
/api/responsie/?Message=lalalal

Does not give a 404.